# Let's encrypt / Traefik / Challenge DNS AWS NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Tags: amazon-web-services, traefik, lets-encrypt

I use traefik as a reverse proxy, I would like to be able to generate a let's encrypt certificate from DNS challenges using route 53 (AWS) providers.

Here is my configuration:

Traefik :

```
# Traefik
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.3.6
    container_name: traefik
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
     # - ./traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml
      - ./acme.json:/acme.json
      - traefik-public-certicate:/certifcates
    ports:
      - "80:80"     # http
      - "443:443" # https
    environment:
      - AWS_REGION=${AWS_REGION}
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
      - AWS_HOSTED_ZONE_ID=${AWS_HOSTED_ZONE_ID}
    command:
      - --api.dashboard=true
      - --providers.docker=true
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.websecure.address=:443
      - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to=websecure
      - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.scheme=https
      - --certificatesresolvers.default.acme.caServer=https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
     # - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.permanent=true
      - --certificatesresolvers.default.acme.email=example@gmail.com
      - --certificatesresolvers.default.acme.storage=acme.json
      - --certificatesresolvers.default.acme.dnschallenge=true
      - --certificatesresolvers.default.acme.dnschallenge.provider=route53
      - --certificatesresolvers.default.acme.dnschallenge.delayBeforeCheck=60
      - --certificatesresolvers.default.acme.dnschallenge.resolvers=1.1.1.1:53,8.8.8.8:53
      - --certificatesresolvers.default.acme.dnschallenge.disablepropagationcheck=true
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.docker.network=app
      - traefik.http.routers.api.rule=Host(`${HOSTNAME}`) && (PathPrefix(`/api`) || PathPrefix(`/dashboard`))
      - traefik.http.routers.api.entrypoints=websecure
      - traefik.http.routers.api.tls.certresolver=default
      - traefik.http.routers.api.service=api@internal
      - traefik.http.routers.api.middlewares=auth # middlewares auth
      - traefik.http.routers.api.tls=true
      - traefik.http.routers.api.tls.domains[0].main=${HOSTNAME}
      - traefik.http.routers.api.tls.domains[0].sans=*.${HOSTNAME}
      - traefik.http.middlewares.auth.basicauth.users=MyUser:MyPassword
    networks:
      - app
```

Example Service :

```
# Ms-example
  ms-example:
    build: ms-example
    container_name: ms-example
    expose:
      - "80"
    volumes:
      - ./ms-example/vhosts:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
      - ./ms-example/:/var/www/html/example
    restart: always
    labels:
      - traefik.docker.network=app
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.ms-security.rule=Host(`${HOSTNAME}`) && PathPrefix(`/v1.0/ms-example`)
      - traefik.http.routers.ms-example.entrypoints=websecure
      - traefik.http.routers.ms-example.tls=true
      - traefik.http.routers.ms-example.tls.certresolver=default
      - traefik.http.routers.ms-example.tls.domains[0].main=${HOSTNAME}
      - traefik.http.routers.ms-example.tls.domains[0].sans=*.${HOSTNAME}
    networks:
      - app
```

The policy given to an IAM user:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "route53:ChangeResourceRecordSets",
                "route53:GetChange",
                "route53:ListHostedZones"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeLoadBalancers",
                "elasticloadbalancing:SetLoadBalancerListenerSSLCertificate"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:ListServerCertificates",
                "iam:GetServerCertificate",
                "iam:UploadServerCertificate"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I get an error on browsers and on postman like this :

```
NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
Subject: TRAEFIK DEFAULT CERT

Issuer: TRAEFIK DEFAULT CERT

Expires on: 20 août 2022

Current date: 20 août 2021

PEM encoded chain:
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MYCERTIFICATE
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

How do I make the certificates valid ? Where am I wrong ?

If you want more info do not hesitate and especially if someone has the slightest idea I am a taker.

**EDIT**

Here is the error I found in the Traefik logs:

```
time="2021-08-23T13:20:22Z" level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"mydomain.fr,*.mydomain.fr\" : unable to generate a certificate for the domains [mydomain.fr *.mydomain.fr]: error: one or more domains had a problem:\n[*.mydomain.fr] [*.mydomain.fr] acme: error presenting token: route53: NoSuchHostedZone: No hosted zone found with ID: use2-az1\n\tstatus code: 404, request id: c702090f-fdcc-4364-a207-a82d58446324\n[mydomain.fr] [mydomain.fr] acme: error presenting token: route53: NoSuchHostedZone: No hosted zone found with ID: use2-az1\n\tstatus code: 404, request id: eb5efd0e-10cd-4369-846c-e0dfe31109de\n" providerName=default.acme
```

mydomain is my domain name.
From what I understand it is because of the host id that its blocking but I do not really understand this party despite numerous research.

Comment: Configuration looks good: do you see anything in the Traefik container logs? In general, or when trying to connect a service?

Comment: @SYN - Sorry to have taken a long time to answer I was taken by the time. Thanks for your help and for your response. I put in EDIT the log error than I found.

Comment: Where does that `use2-az1` comes from? Is that the availability zone? Doesn't look like a valid name, could it be the environment variables passed in your docker-compose, that are invalid? Otherwise, the `NoSuchHostedZone` would suggest you do not have a Route53 zone matching "mydomain.fr".

Comment: @SYN - Ok thanks I am simply using the wrong providers ... I just realized that this domain name was bought on GoogleDomains I suppose I will have to use the GoogleCloudDomain provider for the challengesDNS offered by Traefik?

Comment: Sure! Or instead of DNS challenge, Traefik should be able to use HTTP ones, which won't require integration with any DNS provider (https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/v2.0/user-guides/docker-compose/acme-http/)

Comment: @SYN - thank you very much so I went through the http challenges and it works very well! Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing comments on initial post: unless there's a good reason not to, prefer using LetsEncrypt HTTP challenges. They would not require integrating with a specific DNS.

Comment: This probably shouldn't be the accepted answer as there are plenty of good reasons to do it, specifically generating a wildcard cert for the domain

Comment: If anyone can explain how to set it up, please do. I don't have an aws account for this. Op didn't mind using http challenge. Besides: his zone wasn't in route53 to begin with.